# The bundle is invalid. Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include an armv7 architecture

Tags: ios, xcode

With our app, we don't want to support 3,5" iPhone screens. We also require iOS 8.0, so that leaves the iPhone 4S as the only 3,5" screen that is supported.

We want to exclude the iPhone 4S by removing the armv7 architecture from the valid architectures list when building the App Store binary. But it does not seem to be allowed to do this.

[image: The bundle is invalid. Apps that include an arm64 architecture are required to include an armv7 architecture]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this really not allowed?

Comment: iPhone 5 is also armv7

Comment: Thank you for your response! But I'm sorry, you're wrong. iPhone 5 is armv7s.

Comment: Technically yes, but Xcode 6 dropped the armv7s support, the iPhone 5 fits in the armv7 category.

Comment: You have to support 3.5" screens. If your app is an iPhone-only app, the 3.5" screen will be used when the app is run on an iPad in addition to actual 3.5" iPhone devices.

Comment: But we won't include it in the iPad App Store. Just like "What's app" which is not possible to download for iPad.

Comment: That doesn't matter. All iPhone apps run on an iPad and behave as if they were on a 3.5" screen. I can download any iPhone app on an iPad.

Comment: So Whats the answer ? Is it doable or not ?

Comment: Nope, cannot be done unfortunately. We ended up supporting iPhone 4S anyway...

Answer (score 5):

You can try some options:

-If you have a device plugged in, that device's architecture is the ACTIVE ARCHITECTURE, so you need to unplug the device.

-Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO for targets and project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is already the case unfortunately. Also, this would only be a solution if I DID add "armv7" to the list and still would get this error. Instead I deliberately disabled it.

Comment: "If you have a device plugged in" (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻, like whole hour gone in the dumbest thing ever.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late now, but maybe helps some one else.. For me, this error was when I left iPhone 5S connected, when building ad hoc release for AppStore (or testflight) . If I remove (and leave as iOS Device) - then - no errors.